# Convert datetime string to unix timestamp from string column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column (value) with `mediumtext NULL` where, among other things, are also `datetime` string values saved.
I have to select all `datetime` values and convert them to `Unix datetime`.

the selecting I have to like so

`SELECT value FROM thetable WHERE value REGEXP '^["]+(2[0-9]{3})'`

but ho do I do the uptate tried this

`UPDATE thetable set value = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)  WHERE value REGEXP '^["]+(2[0-9]{3})';`

but it does not affect anything. I think I need a combination of both.

here is a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHWJ5xktwewU1LEb6dBUB/2

[image]

Comment: Examples please.

Comment: create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with a couple of sample rows and update your post with the url and expected result

Comment: Does `SELECT value, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(value)   FROM thetable WHERE value REGEXP '^["]+(2[0-9]{3})'` return what you expect?

Comment: @jarlh Yes is does indeed

Comment: There are no results returned in the link...not suprising really since you are not storing double quotes.

Comment: @p.Salmon sorry I had updated it but did not know that the link will also change

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe6ff75577d477296a1309fd46308140

Comment: No results returned by revised link - quotes and double quotes are discarded when stored - is that what you want? - if so testing for date starting with double quotes is not going to be useful.

Comment: I have no Idea why they are being discarded in my table they are not. And I am able to select them with that query

Comment: `.. WHERE STR_TO_DATE(value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T') IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: @key, did you forget the string delimiters in your fiddle? The " is miss-interpreted as ' by MySQL, so perhaps you meant:  insert into test (id, value) values ... (3, '"2022-02-09T23:00:00:000Z"'), ... ?

Answer (score 0):

So for me it was the combination of these 2 queries

first I had to update the value column to remove the quotes (") from the datetime string value like so:

`UPDATE thetable SET value = REPLACE(value,'"','') WHERE value REGEXP '^["]+([0-9]{4})+(-)+([0-9]{2})+(-)';`

Then update the table to replace the datetime string value from the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` to a format I can covert with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function, and replace the whole column where the datetime is present like so:

`UPDATE thetable set value = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(value, 'T', ' '), '.000Z', ''), '\"', '')) WHERE value REGEXP '^([1-2][0-9]{3})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])T([0-2][0-9]):([0-6][0-9]):([0-3][0-9]).'`